# How to get the maximum value from a dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I wish to get the maximum value of the following dataframe mean table:

```
             SAFETY      TRUST
   AREA                         
   CENTRAL  62.060526  59.008026
   NORTH    65.635526  62.039605
   SOUTH    58.353816  54.330658
   area_1   53.985816  55.799909
   area_2   54.325257  55.536345
   area_3   63.521915  66.896902
   area_4   49.977856  51.172390
   area_5   63.210032  66.811394
```

In order to output this table I did the following code:

```
    descriptiveData = pd.read_csv(fileName, usecols = ['AREA','SAFETY','TRUST'])
    mean = descriptiveData.groupby(['AREA']).mean()
```

Is there any way I can print the Area with the biggest Safety value and the Area with the lowest Trust value?

Comment: `mean["SAFETY"].idxmax()` and `mean["TRUST"].idxmin()`?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

mean['SAFETY'].max() and mean['TRUST'].min()

Here's a list of other operations that can be done: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html